# Последовательность образования слов

Tags: словообразование, суффиксы, приставка

Какое слово нарушает словообразовательную цепочку?

> плыть-заплыть-заплывать-заплыв-заплывший

По-моему первое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нарушает словообразовательную цепочку слово заплыв.

Ха!.. Ну, выкинете вы из цепочки слово ЗАПЛЫВ, и что? Получите:

плыть-заплыть-**заплывать-заплывший**???

**ДЛЯ СПРАВКИ:** от глагола ЗАПЛЫВАТЬ причастие прошедшего времени -- ЗАПЛЫВАВШИЙ **(!)**, а никак не ЗАПЛЫВШИЙ.

**ЗАПЛЫВШИЙ** -- причастие прошедшего времени от глагола **ЗАПЛЫТЬ**.

И потому нарушает приведённую в вопросе словообразовательную цепочку не слово ЗАПЛЫВ, а последнее слово в цепочке -- **ЗАПЛЫВШИЙ**.

Comment: 1) плыть-заплыть-заплывать-заплыв (правильная цепочка) 2) заплыть - заплывший.  Зря не послушали Slava.

Comment: Так меня и не могли услышать. Неправильный ответ собрал три голоса "за" и был принят менее чем за час с момента его публикования,  т. е. ещё до моего ответа.  Меня удивила не столько неправильность принятого ответа (ошибиться может каждый!), сколько  его поддержка нашим сообществом!

Answer (score 4):

Нарушает словообразовательную цепочку слово заплыв. Невозможно принять как правильный вариант, что причастие заплывший образовалось от существительного заплыв. Причастия в русском языке образуются от глаголов.

Answer (score 0):

Нарушает слово "заплывший"

1) плыть-заплыть-заплывать-заплыв (правильная цепочка)

2) заплыть - заплывший